# How to detect inactivity in foreground react-native

Tags: react-native

I used AppState for detect state changes in app. But this only works when app is in `background` and when this is `active`. But I need have time control over `inactive` state.

I need that works only when user is inactive in foreground. But this state also works when app is in `background` state.

This is my code for state control:

```
    AppState.addEventListener('change', state => 
        {
            var blockApp = setTimeout(function(){
                if(inVerify){
                    self.goToVerify();
                }
            }, 1000);

            console.log('AppState changed to', state);

            switch(state){
                case 'active':
                    clearTimeout(blockApp);
                    inVerify = false;
                    break;
                case 'inactive':
                    var x;
                    break;
                case 'background':
                    inVerify = true;
                    blockApp;
                    break;
                default:
                    //nothing state or different state, error in app state
                    break;
            }
        }
    );
```

How can I have control over inactivity time?

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find any solution??

Comment: No, I did not. I still working just with `active` and `background` state.

Comment: Me too facing same. Did you get it work?

Comment: Something to note - `inactive` seems to only apply to iOS: https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate.html#app-states